# success function not called on AJAX call completion in Django for "Add to Favourites Button"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to make "Add to Favorite" button in my application using AJAX call. My html code snippet is

```
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <div id="favDiv"> <a id="favorite" href="/blogs/{{blog.id}}/favorite/"> Add to Favourites </a> </div>
        {% endif %}
```

The jquery for this is

```
$("a#favorite").click(function(){

    var link = $(this).attr("href");

    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: link,
          success: function() 
          { 
            alert("Function succeeded");
            $("#favDiv").html("Favourites");
          },
          error: function()
          {
            alert("Function failed");
          }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

What I want to do, is that when the user clicks on the favorite button then the html inside the div should be replaced by simple text.

My `views.py` contains

```
def favorite_blog(request,blog_id):

    blog = get_object_or_404(Entry, pk=blog_id)

    current_user = request.user
    fav = favorite(user=current_user,entry = blog)    
    fav.save()

    if request.is_ajax():    

        return_message = "Set Favourite"
        return HttpResponse(return_message,mimetype='application/javascript')

    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_blog', args=(),kwargs={'blog_id': blog.id,}))
```

Everything is working fine, when I click the button the database gets updated, however neither the `success: function()` is executing nor the `failure: function()` what could be the possible reason. I have another similar script for like button and that works fine.

Comment: I am not sure if its just a typo in your example code but: you are missing a comma between your success and error functions.

Comment: pdb, you can step through your code and see where it is performing undesirably.

Answer (score 2):

I guess because you're returning a response with mimetype = 'application/javascript' jQuery expects to be able to execute the content of the response as javascript and it fails silently parsing it.

Since you're returning plain text I suggest to fix the mimetype to 'text/plain'

debug hint: add the complete callback fn and do console.log of arguments

```
...
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){ 
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(jqXHR);
},
...
```

Comment: I did as you told, but the problem still persists. Similar to add to favorites I have also made a like button and it's view is very similar and the javascript on success adds a one to the existing like count. I can't understand why this problem is coming up

Comment: I did as you asked but nothing was logged in that... I just fail to understand what could be the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you tried to debug using firebug network tab or the web developer tools in chrome ? there you see the http response code, content etc etc

Comment: I have been trying to use firebug but that is not working in my firefox... I will try chrome and see what happens

Comment: I did conosle.log and sadly I am not seeing anything at all in the firebug debugger I do not understand what the problems is

Comment: @Sachin you should see console.log output in the console tab of firebug (not sure what you mean with the debugger)

Comment: I apologize for my earlier message I had not used firebug previously so did not know how to use it... But now I checked the console tab and again there is noothing